# Angular application not detecting modification from json files

Tags: json, angular, visual-studio-code

I have an angular application that contains 2 json files for translation (english and french ). Well until a week ago everything work perfectly but this last 3 days ng serve no longer detect modification from json files.
But the application is detecting old translations.
Is it maybe a vs code or angular cli or node js update problem?

Any help and thanks.

Comment: If you have a `dist` directory produced by `ng build` command, try to delete this directory. It happened to me a few times

Comment: @An0d Well i tried your solution but still the same problem

Comment: try using ng serve --poll=2000 --watch command

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Well same thing and I also cleared the cache